# group-policy shutdown script runs only on "Reboot", not on "Shutdown"

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, group-policy

We have configured a group-policy object with a shutdown script. When we restart a Windows 10 machine, the script runs as expected. If we shutdown the machine, the script does NOT run at all; instead, the machine shuts down immediately.

We already turned off Fastboot via regkey with no effect.

```
HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\HilbernateEnabled=0
```

Comment: Are you sure the script doesn't run at all? Please add the exact definition of the script. Are you in a domain? Check the Event log for errors. Is the shutdown done via a script or a user-entered command?

Comment: Well, the system shuts down pretty fast (within 3 seconds or so). We also made scripts on shutdown visible. 
Yes it is a domain. All windows 10 clients in the domain are affected. The shutdown is initiated by the user.

Comment: Adding here the exact trigger definition of the scheduled task might help.

Comment: Computerkonfiguration\Richtlinien\Windows-Einstellungen\Skripts\Herunterfahren
shutdown.bat

Comment: I think in english it's like:

Computerconfiguration\Policies\Windows-Settings\Scripts\Shutdown

shutdown.bat

Comment: If you have resolved the issue, better add an answer below for future readers and mark it as accepted (the V button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Shutdown\Require use of fast startup resolved the issue.

Comment: You don't specify to which value you have set it, mine was initially at "Not Configured". I assumed you meant to set it to "Disabled", but that didn't work for me. The only thing that worked for me was to disable Hiberboot as specified here: https://serverfault.com/questions/793295/how-to-disable-fast-startup-using-a-group-policy Then I could leave "Require use of fast startup" at "Not configured".